# Swipebox.js gallery image repeats

Tags: jquery, html

My idea was to use [Swipebox](http://brutaldesign.github.io/swipebox/) to display a one separate image as gallery thumbnail but to show a set of other images in the "lightbox-mode" of the gallery. Seems to work pretty ok exempt some of the gallery images are repeated in the "lightbox-mode".

**My HTML**

```
<div class="gallery">
<!-- gallery images -->
<a href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/resized-images-new/40E473CE-9C84-4D7A-A1A5-31B2D8A2A35C" class="swipebox" data-title="Image_1">
<a href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/resized-images-new/C8C44FD6-C258-41B4-B2EA-F2E6057F210B" class="swipebox" data-title="Image_2">
<a href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/resized-images-new/9DDEC32A-1823-4F6B-B8AC-956C7443C9E8" class="swipebox" data-title="Image_3">
<a href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/resized-images-new/78A88D94-1004-4138-8824-2BF7F1C39A6D" class="swipebox" data-title="Image_4">
<!-- thumbnail image-->
<img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/resized-images-new/F7606CF0-C758-4054-A691-9240192EFB6A">
</div>
```

**My FIDDLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/Zzw7M/

Does anyone have any idea why this is occurring?

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Zzw7M/1/

You need to wrap the launcher image with one of the `<a>` tags. Otherwise, I think the plugin automatically does this with the last image causing a duplicate image in the gallery.

```
<div class="gallery"> 
    <a href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/resized-images-new/40E473CE-9C84-4D7A-A1A5-31B2D8A2A35C" class="swipebox" data-title="Image_1">
    <a href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/resized-images-new/C8C44FD6-C258-41B4-B2EA-F2E6057F210B" class="swipebox" data-title="Image_2">
    <a href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/resized-images-new/9DDEC32A-1823-4F6B-B8AC-956C7443C9E8" class="swipebox" data-title="Image_3">
    <a href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/resized-images-new/78A88D94-1004-4138-8824-2BF7F1C39A6D" class="swipebox" data-title="Image_4">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/resized-images-new/F7606CF0-C758-4054-A691-9240192EFB6A">
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: LOL I was cleaning up my and thought the </a> looked a bit lonely and out of place there... so I deleted it :) Thank you JSUar